# Problema con pagina github

Tags: github, github-pages

Estoy creando un perfil para un usuario de GitHub y estoy siguiendo los pasos del sitio `https://pages.github.com/`.

El problema es que el resultado es: `https://usuario.github.io/perfil.github.io`.

Sigo los pasos para solucionar el problema creando el branch `gh-pages` y el resultado es le mismo: `https://usuario.github.io/perfil.github.io`.

Realice los pasos desde la terminal y lo hice con windows desde la app de escritorio y no logro resolverlo.

Como puedo solucionar esto?

Agradesco de antemano!

Comment: Las instrucciones allí dicen que el push se hace sobre master.

Comment: Claro, eso es lo hago en el primer paso y el resultado es `https://usuario.github.io/perfil.github.io`